# Visualforce format an output number depending on decimal value, if decimal is zero then just display the number

Tags: visualforce, rendered, formatting

I am trying to display multiple values in a page which are currency fields set with 2 decimals (in the object).

[image]

Currently I am using the below expresion to format the values which works great:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number,$ ###,###,##0.00}">
    <apex:param value="{!number_value__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

The problem that I have is if the value is 10.00
I want to display it as $ 10 and not as $ 10.00

I am guessing I will need to use rendered property but how can I check if the {!number_value__c} has as a decimal 00 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the easiest trick. Multiply the value with 100 and then use `MOD` function to find the remainder upon diving 100.

> Basically, if value is 10.00 then it should be 10.00*100 = 1000, So MOD(1000,100) will give you remainder 0
>
> If value is 10.05 then it should be 10.05*100 = 1005, So MOD(1005,100) will give you remainder greater than 0

This works for me

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number,$ ###,###,##0.00}" rendered="{!MOD(number_value__c*100, 100)>0 }">
    <apex:param value="{!number_value__c}" />
</apex:outputText>

<apex:outputText value="{0, number,$ ###,###,##0}" rendered="{!MOD(number_value__c*100, 100)=0}">
    <apex:param value="{!number_value__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Thank you, I ammend {!MOD(bankst.BF010_Month_6__c*100, 100)>0 } to {!MOD(bankst.BF010_Month_6__c*100, 100)!=0 } as I have some negative values